# Exception when I try create JNDI Subcontext from JUnit

Tags: java, junit, jboss, jndi, initial-context

My purpose - create test for DAO layer. My Hibernate config has datasourse specified throught JNDI. Also I use Jboss 5.1 so transaction lookup is necessary.

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:jdbc/MysqlDS</property>
 <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
 <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
```

To make test I need bind these things. Todo this I create class util to bind. Full code below

public class RegisteringJNDIWithDataSource {

```
public static final String JNDI_MY_DS = "java:jdbc/MysqlDS";

private static final String MYSQL_USER = "user";
private static final String MYSQL_PASS = "pass";
private static final String MYSQL_HOST = "localhost";

public static String CTX_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory";
public static String CTX_URL_PKG_RPEFIXES = "org.jboss.naming";


private void startRegistry() throws NamingException, RemoteException {

    System.out.println(LocateRegistry.getRegistry());
    Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

    NamingServer server = new NamingServer();
    NamingContext.setLocal(server);
    System.out.println("RMI registry Stared.");
}

public InitialContext createInitialContextContext() throws NamingException {
    System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, CTX_URL_PKG_RPEFIXES);
    System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, CTX_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);

    InitialContext initialContextcontext = new InitialContext();
    return initialContextcontext;
}

/**
 * Registry the following JNDIs
 *
 * @throws RemoteException
 * @throws NamingException
 */
public void registrate() throws RemoteException, NamingException {
    startRegistry();
    InitialContext ic;
    ic = createInitialContextContext();


    String[] cxts = JNDI_MY_DS.split("/");

    String inCxt = cxts[0];
    createSubcontext(ic, inCxt);
    for (int i = 1; i < cxts.length - 1; i++) {
        // if the data source name is like java:/comp/mysqldatasource
        // this takes care of creating subcontexts in jndi
        inCxt = inCxt + "/" + cxts[i];
        createSubcontext(ic, inCxt);
    }

    ic.rebind(JNDI_MY_DS, createMysqlDataSource("db_name"));


    // the following requires JBoss dependent class. May be sth can be done to generalize this

    TransactionManager tm = new CustomTXNManager();
    ic.bind("java:/TransactionManager", tm);

    UserTransaction ut = new CustomUserTransaction();
    ic.bind("UserTransaction", ut);
}

private static Context createSubcontext(Context ctx, String cxtName) throws NamingException {
    System.out.println(" creating subcontext " + cxtName);
    Context subctx = ctx;
    Name name = ctx.getNameParser("").parse(cxtName);
    for (int pos = 0; pos < name.size(); pos++) {
        String ctxName = name.get(pos);
        try {
            subctx = (Context) ctx.lookup(ctxName);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            subctx = ctx.createSubcontext(ctxName);
        }
        // The current subctx will be the ctx for the next name component
        ctx = subctx;
    }
    return subctx;
}

public void unregistrate() throws NamingException {
    InitialContext context;
    context = createInitialContextContext();
    context.unbind(JNDI_MY_DS);
}

private MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource createMysqlDataSource(String database) throws NamingException {
    MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource;
    dataSource = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(MYSQL_USER);
    dataSource.setPassword(MYSQL_PASS);
    dataSource.setServerName(MYSQL_HOST);
    dataSource.setPort(3306);
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(database);
    return dataSource;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    RegisteringJNDIWithDataSource dataSource = new RegisteringJNDIWithDataSource();
    try {
        dataSource.registrate();

    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static class CustomTXNManager extends TransactionManagerImple implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomTXNManager() {
    }
}

public static class CustomUserTransaction extends UserTransactionImple implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomUserTransaction() {
    }
}
```

}

All works fine if call from console. But when I call this from JUnit I got exception.

```
 @Test
 public void test() throws RemoteException, NamingException {
     RegisteringJNDIWithDataSource j = new RegisteringJNDIWithDataSource();
     j.registrate();
 }


    javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException
at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.createSubcontext(RegistryContext.java:230)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:464)
```

Comment: i would suggest to avoid JUnit for testing the DAO layer. 3rd party mock up tools like Easy mock can be used plus you have the advantage that your tests would not fail in case there in no data in db.

Comment: You may find out easier to avoid JNDI in JUnit tests. You can still test your DAO layer, but use a different Hibernate configuration when you run your tests. Your test Hibernate configuration can create a simple data source from properties rather than from JNDI.

Comment: Separate configuration is a good idea. Initially I though about, but finally don't like idea that support of two configuration is necessary.

Comment: Mock is a good idea too, but I would prefer to make like a integration test. In some place of business logic I use stored procedure, it makes complications to test.